# What's the difference between "java.vendor" vs "java.vm.vendor"?

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

Is there a difference between **java.vendor** and **java.vm.vendor** properties in Java?

It appears that the two are always the same. Is that a correction assumption?

If you know of scenarios where these two values are not the same please list them.

Edit:

I'm trying to figure out which property would tell me if current java is Oracle or Apple or OpenJDK or another JVM. Until now I checked for both of these properties. But is it safe to assume that I only need to check **java.vendor**?

Answer (score 2):

Due to java API, **java.vendor** is a java runtime environment vendor and **java.vm.vendor** is a java virtual machine implementation vendor. [There is a number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) of different JVMs, so the values may differ in some specific cases. And it's not guaranted, that JVM will always return both values.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which property would tell me if current java is Oracle or Apple or OpenJDK or another JVM. Until now I checked for both of these properties. But is it safe to assume that I only need to check java.vendor?

Comment: Why are you checking this? It seems to me that if JVMs differ in some way that you would have to check this that there is really no guarantee of consistent behaviour in future versions no matter what you check.

Comment: Agree with @WillShackleford, it seems, there is no any guarantee, that nothing changes in the future. So, if at the moment **java.vendor** gives you expected result, you can rely on it now, but just now and for current JRE versions you have.